# Upgrading individual modules in Centos

Tags: centos, dnf

I have just installed Centos Streams and found that the version of Podman in Container Tools is only 1.0.5. The latest release is 1.3. I find that strange because the idea of Centos Streams is to enable the latest upstream modules...

I cannot find a way to override the app streams or modules in Centos Streams (or RHEL 8) to install the latest upstream version of Podman and Buildah. How do you do that?

Thanks